# Installing .deb from MobileSafari

Tags: objective-c, ios, mobile-safari, jailbreak, deb

Does anyone know how to make .deb files install directly from MobileSafari on the iPhone/iPod touch/iPad? I know it's possible, as seen with the 'lima' project, but I have no idea what it's supposed to be written in, or how. If someone could tell me I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question makes me shudder. Installing .deb packages via a web browser?!

Comment: Yes sir. It's been done, and done well many times, but I have no idea how to do it. lol

Comment: @user966197 It would be a good idea to mention in the question body (besides the tag) that you refer to JailBroken devices only

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a detailed answer to your question, it shows the way on doing it:

1st: A download plugin for MobileSafari to actually download the .deb

2nd: Once the download has been completed you execute dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb (for example via system()

But this won't take care about dependencies and other things which is important when dealing with DEBIAN packages. For that you'll have to utilize the apt library like Cydia does.

Comment: @user966197 is there any success?